# What fuses for 100A, 3-ph disconnects

Tags: wiring, fuses, three-phase

I've been looking at 3 phase disconnects, and I'm uncertain what the rated amperage means in this context. Since each blade (phase) has its own fuse in a fusable disconnect, does that mean that for a 100A disconnect you would give each phase a 100A fuse? Or, would you use a 30A fuse for each?

Comment: The current rating is per phase.

Answer (score 3):

As @transistor already stated, I would give each blade/phase/leg a 100A fuse.

**However:** I have been working with mains power for decades. So while *I* would do that myself, I would *never* recommend that someone with little enough experience to need to ask this question (and I mean absolutely no offense here. Everyone has to learn some time, I'd just rather you *not* 'learn' by getting hurt/killed) be messing with 3-phase power unsupervised. Even when each phase is labeled 220V/240V, accidentally touching any 2 of them can hit you with ~340Vrms/~480Vp-p ... that's WHOLE LOT MORE voltage to push lethal current through you than accidentally touching 2 terminals on a 110V lightswitch!

So, yes you should get the 100A fuses (probably...depends on the wire guage you're feeding from the switch), but please, ***please*** have someone who is knowledgeable/experienced present to ensure that you can complete the work *safely*.

Comment: I agree that if you are asking about 100A fuses on 3ph mains that you should have some experience before on mains circuits. At least you should correctl terminate and bolt the wires, which aren't as easily flexible, you do have to know and see some tricks how to bend this snake and show it the way to the fuse block.

Comment: I'm not wiring anything. I'm just going to buy the stuff and have a licensed electrician wire it up. It's funny, I have an EE/CE degree, but they don't teach you basic stuff like this in class (then again, I never took power courses). It's just a basic rating question, and when it comes to code, I'd rather pay someone to do it so that it'll pass inspection.

Comment: @Maxthecat I'm glad to hear you already chose the safer route & I don't have to worry about you frying yourself somewhere while trying to follow my suggestion. As far as 'what to buy' goes; you should be fine @ <= 100A by using the lower of the 100A switch rating, or the NEC recommended amperage of your wiring you'll be running from the switch to your distribution panel(s).

Answer (score 1):

Your first question to ask is what is the amperage rating of the wiring downstream of the disconnect?

If you are connecting #10 AWG copper THHN conductors to the load side of the disconnect then do not fuse with anything larger than 30 Amp fuses.

I believe that if you are installing 100 Amp Fuses you will need #2 AWG Copper wire.

I don't have a National Electrical Code book in front of me but I think Conductor Ampacities are listed in 310.15

And I will also note that you should have some awareness Instantanous current rating of the system feeding the line side of the disconnect.  If you are talking 480 Volt 3 phase it is not unusual to have Instanteous Fault currents of 15 or 20K.  You want to make sure that your disconnect is rated for at least the ICL rating of your system if not more.

Answer (score 0):

Note: i'm a brit so details and terminology in this post are likely to be british. The general principles should apply most places though.

I assume the device you are reffering to is what we would call a "switchfuse". A device with a switch switching the three phases and possiblly the neutral followed by a set of fuses one for each phase.

In general current ratings are per conductor. In a three phase system for the most part (harmonics and phase offsets can screw this up but in practice it's rare for this to be a significant problem) neutral currents from different phases cancel such that the neutral current is no higher than the highest phase current. So in a 100A three phase switchfuse you could fit three fuses each UP TO 100A.

What fuses you actually fit will depend on the design of the circuits both upstream and downstream of your protective device and ultimately on the requirements of the load.

There may be reasons to use a switchfuse rated higher than the fuses you intend to fit. Such as.

- Switchgear tends to come in a more limited range of current ratings than the fuses to go inside it.
- It may make installation easier to have a row of identical devices than a row of devices of mixed size.
- Switchgear with higher current ratings is likely to have support for larger conductors and/or more wiring room. Larger than normal conductors can be needed where long runs would otherwise cause excessive volt drop. More wiring room can be useful with certain cable types (with singles in trunking you can often just push slack back into the trunking, with sheathed cables and especially with armoured cables that have to be glanded you have less flexibility).
- Switchgear with higher current ratings may also have higher "breaking capacity". This can be important if the gear is installed where the prospective fault currents are high.
- You may chose to oversize both the switchgear and cables in anticipation of future changes but keep the actual fuses matched to the requirements of the present load.
- Occasionally a device intended for three phase may end up getting used in a situation where the supply isn't actually three phase (or in the case of a transfer switch is only three phase some of the time). So the neutral currents don't cancel and a larger device is needed to give a sufficient current rating on the neutral.

I would strongly advise you to involve your electrician in the design process including selecting what equipment to use at least the first few times.